# Changing reference parameter value in fortran from calling function in c#

Tags: c#, reference, fortran, cancellation

I have a dll written in fortran with a subroutine that takes a logical parameter as input. I want to use this to control cancellation of the subroutine, and have the possibility to change it's value in the calling c# code. Below is a small example of what I have tested with.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static bool _b;
        [DllImport(dllName: "TestFortran.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern void TestBool(ref bool b);


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            TestFortranBool();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void TestFortranBool()
        {
            _b = true;
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TestBool(ref _b));
            Console.WriteLine($"C# :{_b}");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _b = false;
            Console.WriteLine($"C# :{_b}");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _b = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"C# :{_b}");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _b = false;
            Console.WriteLine($"C# :{_b}");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _b = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"C# :{_b}");

            t.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

and fortran code:

```
module FortranTesting
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
contains
  
  
  subroutine TestBool(b)

  ! Expose subroutine TestFortran to users of this DLL
  !
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::TestBool
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE,ALIAS:"TestBool" :: TestBool
  
  logical(c_bool),intent(in) ::  b
  write(*,*) "Inside fortran"
  write(*,*) "F :", b
  call sleep(5)
  write(*,*) "F : ", b
  call sleep(5)
  write(*,*) "F : ", b
  call sleep(5)
  write(*,*) "F : ", b
  
  end subroutine TestBool
end module FortranTesting
```

What I get from this is:

> C# :True
> Inside fortran
> F : T
>
> C# :False
> F :  T
>
> C# :True
> F :  T
>
> C# :False
> F :  T
>
> C# :True

What I would like is that F (fortran) alternates with C#.
I have tried the opposite when reading the variable from C# and changing the variable in Fortran, which works as expected.

Comment: Not sure if directly related to the source of your problem, but you could not mark the parameter as intent(in), and maybe declare it as volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an way to solve the cancellation.
I give an exampel code that returns a value to the fortran code (and hence can be used to cancel the fortran subroutine/function):

c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [DllImport(dllName: "TestFortran.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal unsafe static extern void TestCallBack([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ActionRefInt callBack);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void ActionRefInt(ref int i);


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestCallBack();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TestCallBack()
        {
            var callbackHandler = new ActionRefInt(OnCallBackInt);
            TestCallBack(callbackHandler);
        }

        private static void OnCallBackInt(ref int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"C#: Value before change: {i}");
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine($"C#: Value after change: {i}");
        }

    }
}
```

And Fortran code:

```
  module FortranTesting
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none

  contains

  subroutine TestCallBack(callBack)
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::TestCallBack
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE,ALIAS:"TestCallBack" :: TestCallBack
  external        ::  callBack
  integer         ::  test
  
  test  = 1
  write(*,*) "F: Test before callback: ", test
  call callBack(test)
  write(*,*) "F: Test after callback: ", test
  end subroutine TestCallBack
  end module FortranTesting
```

This code produce the following output:

> F: Test before callback:  1
>
> C#: Value before change: 1
>
> C#: Value after change: 2
>
> F: Test after callback:  2

Answer (score 0):

I do not know C#, so I cannot help you on that side. However, as long as you can interface your C# with C, there is also a way to connect your Fortran code to C# as well. For that, you will have to add the `bind(C)` attribute to your Fortran code,

```
module FortranTesting
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine TestBool(b) bind(C, name = "TestBool")
        ! Expose subroutine TestFortran to users of this DLL
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TestBool

        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_bool
        implicit none
        logical(c_bool), intent(in) ::  b

        write(*,*) "Inside Fortran:"
        write(*,*) "F :", b
        call sleep(5)
        write(*,*) "F : ", b
        call sleep(5)
        write(*,*) "F : ", b
        call sleep(5)
        write(*,*) "F : ", b

    end subroutine TestBool
end module FortranTesting
```

This code should be now callable from C as `TestBool(b)`, with an input argument `b` that has the type `_Bool`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @King.. however there is no problem with the interface to c# (or C for that matter) - the `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT` and `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE,ALIAS` takes care of that in Intel Fortran (I think in gfortran you would need the `BIND C`). All parameters passed to and from the subroutine are handled correctly as long as I don't have to read them intermediately in fortran (to check if C# changed them). Reading intermediately in C# parameters passed to fortran is not a problem though. It is the intermediate reading in fortran code that is the issue.